# how to know the count of number of rows deleted using pandas

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas, pymysql

Here from this 2 .csv files filtering is done and common emailid's are deleted,I am able to get the total after deletion ,But is there any option that gives how many rows are deleted using pandas.

using mysql :
delete a from data a, data1 b  where a.email=b.email; select row_count(); 
How can this be done using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

colnames=['id','emailid']

data=pd.read_csv("input.csv",names=colnames,header=None)

colnames=['email']

data1= pd.read_csv("compare.csv",names=colnames,header=None)

emailid_suppress1=data1['email'].str.lower()

suppress_md5=data[~data['emailid'].isin(emailid_suppress1)]

print suppress_md5.count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need `sum` of `True`s values which are processes like `1`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('abcde'), 'emailid':list('klmno')})
print (data)
  id emailid
0  a       k
1  b       l
2  c       m
3  d       n
4  e       o

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'email':list('ABCKLDEFG')})
print (data1)
  email
0     A
1     B
2     C
3     K
4     L
5     D
6     E
7     F
8     G

emailid_suppress1=data1['email'].str.lower()

print ((~data['emailid'].isin(emailid_suppress1)).sum())
3

suppress_md5=data[~data['emailid'].isin(emailid_suppress1)]
print (suppress_md5)
  id emailid
2  c       m
3  d       n
4  e       o
```

EDIT:

```
print ((data['emailid'].isin(emailid_suppress1)).sum())
2

suppress_md5=data[data['emailid'].isin(emailid_suppress1)]

print (suppress_md5)
  id emailid
0  a       k
1  b       l
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. But I am looking for the number of rows deleted here it should be 2 as K,L are in both emailid and email .For sum() is similar to count .This is function i need to use for large csv files. Need function that gives number of rows deleted

Comment: @DivyaNagandla - I understand, then just remove `~`, so dont invert by `~`

Comment: @DivyaNagandla - sorry, I dont know `bash` :(

Comment: how can we get the count of number of deleted rows while using

df.query('line_race != 0')

Comment: @DivyaNagandla - use `len(df.query('line_race != 0') )`

Comment: Thanks a lot jezrael:)